# Writing continuously to named pipe

Tags: shell-script, pipe, fifo

I have a problem that I can't seem to solve involving two named pipes. Basically, I have two processes that I don't have control over. They are communicating via named pipes (`mknod pipe p`). Process one is a GPS driver that outputs messages in NMEA0183 format. Process two is a navigation application that reads NMEA0183 data to get location and date/time from GPS. I need to adjust this data (reason: google for WNRO or ask).

1. First process is continuously writing data (~5-8 lines of text) in 1 second intervals into /var/run/one.pipe and leaving it there until it is read(?)
2. Second process is reading this data from the named pipe. I can change the name of the named pipe to read from. I changed it to /var/run/two.pipe

The final goal is to read data from one.pipe, do some processing, and then pass it to two.pipe. However, for the meantime and for testing I am just trying to copy the data one by one from one.pipe to two.pipe. I figured it's not feasible wasting time on the whole processing until I can manage to complete this (simpler?) task.

A very simple shell script works: copy.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cat one.pipe > two.pipe &
```

Now I captured some of the data that the source process writes to `one.pipe` and tried to manually write it to `two.pipe` to be read by the reading process:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  echo "\$GPGGA,,,,,,,,*12" > two.pipe
  echo "\$GPGSA,,,,,,,,*23" > two.pipe
  echo "\$GPRMC,,,,,,,,*34" > two.pipe
  echo "\$GPGSV,,,,,,,,*45" > two.pipe
  echo "\$GPGSV,,,,,,,,*56" > two.pipe
  echo "\$GPGSV,,,,,,,,*67" > two.pipe
  # checksums (*xx) are just examples here
  sleep 1 > two.pipe
done
```

Now this doesn't work well. If I compare `cat one.pipe` vs. `cat two.pipe` I can see that the messages in `two.pipe` don't "pile up", while they do from the original process, that writes into `one.pipe`. E.g., if I start my script, it should write to the named pipe and continue to do so on and on. When I read that pipe with `cat` it should output all the data so far (assuming the fifo-buffer hasn't been filled yet). It is first-in-first-out afterall, isn't it?!

Also, cat now frequently stops seemingly randomly. And finally, also the process that I can't control which is reading from `two.pipe` seems to not work well with the data/causes the script to terminate.

I don't even understand why the script terminates, even though it contains an infinite loop?!

What am I overseeing here? If this is not feasible to write in shell, C would also be an option.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> while true; do
>   echo "\$GPGGA,,,,,,,,*12" > two.pipe
>   echo "\$GPGSA,,,,,,,,*23" > two.pipe
>   ...
> ```

Each `... > two.pipe` line from your script will open and **close** the `two.pipe` fifo, and closing it may cause any read from the other end of the pipe to return end-of-file, and the `cat` to exit.

I suggest for starting just to open the fifo *once* for your whole script with `exec`:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec > two.pipe

while true; do
  echo "\$GPGGA,,,,,,,,*12"
  echo "\$GPGSA,,,,,,,,*23"
  ...
  sleep 1
done
```

---

You can "pin" a fifo by opening both of its ends into the same handle with eg.

```
exec 7<>two.fifo
```

As long as the process doing it hasn't exited and hasn't closed the file descriptor `7`, that will make sure that the processes reading from it won't get an end-of-file when all the other handles to its *writing* end are closed, and the processes writing to it won't be killed by a `SIGPIPE` when all the other handles to its *reading* end are closed.

Also, opening both ends of a named fifo at the same time won't block.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. Now I tried that, but still seems to terminate randomly (why even with infinite loop???). And also in this example data doesn't stack. If I start the script and wait a couple of seconds and then do "cat two.pipe" I can see that writing to the pipe stopped at "sleep 1" during the first run of the loop (added a counter to reassure myself).

Comment: If you use the script as in my example, and then do a `cat two.pipe`, the `cat` will print, in order everything that the script writes to `two.pipe`. When you kill the `cat`, the script script will be killed too by the `SIGPIPE` signal when trying to write to a pipe with no readers. (Notice that `echo` is a shell built-in; it's not the `echo` which will be killed, but the whole script).

Comment: Sometimes it seems "cat" is reading to fast...but it shouldn't exit without EOF, no? And to circumvent SIGPIPE, can I use printf instead of echo?

Comment: `cat` could also be killed by `SIGPIPE` if trying to write to a pipe with no readers. That what happens in `cat file | sed 1q`. `printf` or `echo` makes no difference. If you want to keep a named pipe live for random readers & writers, you should "pin" it from another place, as I explained in 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at that. But why does writing to the pipe stop at the first sleep command?

Comment: It does not -- in my example.

Comment: I mean, it stops and waits there if I don't read simultaneously. In my opinion it should continue filling the named pipe until the buffer is full, no?!

Comment: That's exactly what is does. If you want it to fill the buffer and block on write sooner, remove the `sleep`. Trying to *open* the write end of a pipe will block until the read end is opened too (and vice versa). You can make the open return immediately by opening both ends at once, but then you won't be able to detect via EOF or SIGPIPE/EPIPE when another process has closed its end of the pipe. Anyways, it seems that you're trying to find an explanation which accomodates your assumptions, instead  of giving them up -- and I'm afraid I cannot help you with that.

Comment: If I remove "sleep", is there another option to pause writing for a second?

Comment: the `sleep 1` works fine if you want to pause writing for a second after each loop cycle. If you don't want it to pause (and have it fill the pipe sooner) you remove it ;-).

Comment: I want it to pause, but just for 1 second. Right now it appears as if it is waiting there for something to read the pipe.

Comment: That's expected. When the pipe buffer is full, any write will block until a read removes some of the data and makes space available. It's not clear what your problem is. You may be running into issues with programs which are doing their own i/o buffering (eg. `sed`, `awk`, etc) instead of reading or writing directly as `cat` or `echo` and are trying to pin down the cause elsewhere. Or you may be just expecting a pipe to discard the oldest data where there's no more space for new data to be written to -- but this is **not** how named or unnamed pipes work on Unix.

Comment: In the end I did it in C. There, I could flush the output after every line. That made it work as (I) expected.